# Convert Custom String format to Date object

Tags: .net, powershell

At my work, I'm getting some dates from AD attributes that were set by other scripts in the company, but to a unfriendly format I would say.

The Strings are the following: 201710191528
Which Stand to: YYYYMMDDHHmm

I want to convert this to a Date Object but so far without success.

I though about using StringBuilder to manipulate the String first to a format I can use on Get-Date() doing the following:

```
$strB = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$strB.Append("201710191528")
$strB.Insert(10,":")
$strB.Insert(8," ")
$strB.Insert(6,"-")
$strB.Insert(4,"-")
```

And this works. StringBuilder will have "2017-10-19 15:28" which is perfect for Get-Date where I can just use it will work.

Now, I will be processing thousands of strings like this regularly.
Is there something more efficient? 
I couldn't to get it to work with string formats.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[datetime]::ParseExact('201710191528','yyyyMMddHHmm',$null)
```

http://winpowershell.blogspot.in/2006/09/systemdatetime-parseexact.html

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 0):

`201710191528` will be converted in `2017-10-19 15:28` :

```
$strDate = "201710191528"
Get-Date([datetime]::ParseExact($strDate,'yyyyMMddHHmm',$null)) -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
```

Comment: This is redundant. 

The Object type DateTime is already being cast, so doing the ParseExact in this case will return a DateTime Object. 
No need for Get-Date. 
Thank you for the suggestion though.